# cygwin time command always returns 0.00 for usertime

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm trying to benchmark the execution time of a Windows program that is run from within cygwin and am having trouble getting the 'time' command to produce value for anything other than wallclock time.

For example

```
time ghostpdl/bin/gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=ppmraw -o temp.ppm -r2000 \
  ghostpdl/examples/transparency_example.ps
```

returns:

```
real    0m39.313s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The /bin/time command acts the same way, claiming that 0% CPU resources were used:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:41.07elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 182016maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (721major+0minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

It does seem to be possible to retrieve cpu time and usage for a windows executable from cygwin since top does it:

```
  PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                    
351568 Marcos H   8   0  576m 480m  45m R   99  5.9   0:10.84 gswin64c                                                                                                                   
352120 Marcos H   8   0  115m 109m  36m R   61  1.3   0:52.79 top
```

Why top has 61% cpu usage on cygwin is different question.  And I do appreciate that the user time returned by 'time' and TIME+ reported by top are not the same thing, however I'd be happy with either of them.

When running cygwin programs (e.g. /bin/sort) the values returned by time are reasonable.

BTW, I'm running on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit with cygwin 2.2.1 x86_64 (that's what uname -a returns).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For 32 bit version of cygwin you can install the package for `procps`.
This isn't available for the 64 bit version of cygwin